# Storing NSArray/NSMuatbleArray in File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm beginning to store an NSArray in file, but I keep getting nil as a response...

The Apple docs say that nil means your file doesn't exist, but I'm pretty sure mine does (I'm probably not building my path correctly)...

Here is the code that I use to store my NSArray in a file...

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scorecards" ofType:@"dgs"];

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"J", @"ANA", @"MY", @"GDON", nil];

[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSArray *mynewArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSLog(@"%@", [mynewArray objectAtIndex:2]);
```

I also took a screenshot of Xcode to show you guys that my file does exist...

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

The file is clearly saved in the group **ScorecardsSaved** and the file is called **scorecards** with the extension **dgs** (something I made up for my specific application - Dot Golf Scorecard - dgs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, your file path uses the `pathForResource` method, thus it will point to a location in your application bundle, which is not writable.

Instead, you have to write to the application document directory on the device / simulator.

```
NSURL *documentsDirectory = 
   [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
     inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectory 
   URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"storecards.dgs"];
```

So if your bundle version of the document contains some seed data, copy it to the app documents directory first.

Comment: But I need the filePath to be a NSstring not an  NSurl

Comment: `NSString *path = [myURL path];` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];

[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```